# What is a page-wrap div and what is it used for?

Tags: html, class

I'm seeing `div class="page-wrap"` used extensively in web applications.

What is the convention for the `page-wrap` class, what goes inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on your css layout you are applying... Sometimes, people use wrap containers to use sticky footer technique (header and content in the wrap, footer after the wrap - google it); sometimes with this wrapper the designer just wants to fix the entire page to certain width and center it (not saying that this is the best way or that there is a best way), etc... It is really subjective, because it is mostly a design thing.

Answer (score 1):

By convention it can take ONLY the following:

```
*
```

Yes, everything. I am sure there's no such convention about it. The possible reason to use this div tag with page-wrap class may be to clarify that before it is the header region and after it come sthe footer part. So if I have a simple 5-page website, I'll have a common header and common footer, shared by each of 5 pages. My about-us page will be different from my contact-us page only inside `<div class="page-wrap">`.